How to use PixiJS MeshGeometry
I just started to learn PixiJs and exploring the MeshGeometry but unable to make it work.
I need to use an image as texture on a triangle. Please advice me on what should I do.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/8.3.0/pixi.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script>
        (async () => {
        // Create the PixiJS application
        const app = new PIXI.Application();

        // Initialize the application
        await app.init({
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            backgroundColor: 0x1099bb,
        });

        // Append the canvas to the DOM
        document.body.appendChild(app.canvas);

        // Load the texture
        const texture = await PIXI.Assets.load('../images/pimple.png');

        // Define triangle vertices
        const vertices = new Float32Array([
            400, 0, // Vertex 1 (x, y)
            0, 600, // Vertex 2 (x, y)
            800, 600, // Vertex 3 (x, y)
        ]);

        // Define texture coordinates (UV mapping)
        const uvs = new Float32Array([
            0.5, 0,   // UV for Vertex 1
            0, 1,     // UV for Vertex 2
            1, 1,     // UV for Vertex 3
        ]);

        // Define the indices for the triangle
        const indices = new Uint16Array([0, 1, 2]);

        // Create the geometry (simplified in v8)
        const geometry = new PIXI.MeshGeometry({indices:indices,positions:vertices,uvs:uvs});
        console.log(geometry)
        // Create the mesh using the geometry and texture
        const mesh = new PIXI.Mesh(geometry, texture);
        console.log(mesh)
        // Add the mesh to the stage
        app.stage.addChild(mesh);
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>

I'm expecting a triangle with a pimple texture on it. Thank you.
